# Java Scanner class reading strings

Tags: java, string, class, duplicates, java.util.scanner

I got the following code:

```
        int nnames;
    String names[];

    System.out.print("How many names are you going to save: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    nnames = in.nextInt();
    names = new String[nnames];

    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        System.out.print("Type a name: ");
        names[i] = in.next();
    }

    System.out.println(names[0]);
```

When I run this code, the scanner will only pick up the first name and not the last name. And it will sometimes skip a line when trying to enter a name, it will show up as if I had left the name blank and skip to the next name. I don't know what's causing this.

I hope someone can help me!

EDIT: I have tried in.nextLine(); it fixes the complete names but it still keeps a line, here is an example of the output:

```
How many names are you going to save:  3
Type a name: Type a name: John Doe
Type a name: John Lennon
```

Comment: Exact match of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466418/java-scanner-class-reading-strings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of:

```
in.next();
```

Use:

```
in.nextLine();
```

`nextLine()` reads the characters until it finds a new line character `'\n'`

Answer (score 3):

After your initial nextInt(), there's still an empty newline in your input.  So just add a nextLine() after your nextInt(), and then go into your loop:

```
...
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
nnames = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine(); // gets rid of the newline after number-of-names
names = new String[nnames];

for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
    System.out.print("Type a name: ");
    names[i] = in.nextLine();
}
...
```

Comment: +1 I've lost a programming contest recently because I used next() instead of nextLine() to skip that first \\n . That was so stupid :(

Comment: Was that CodeJam, by chance?  I competed this year for the first time, and I got crushed - didn't even make it into round 2.  But I had fun in the qual and round 1, and I'll be back next year.

Answer (score 2):

[Scanner.next](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) stops reading when it encounters a delimiter, which is a whitespace. Use the `nextLine` method instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
System.out.println()
```

Instead of:

```
System.out.print()
```