# String input from user not getting accepted inside case statement?

Tags: java

Following is my code . It is a basic menu driven java program to utilize all the string functions.
But, consisting of functions having more than one string the second string input is not being considered.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Strt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1;
        System.out.println("Enter a String:");
        s1 = n.nextLine();
        int choice;
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for Length of the string\n Enter 2 to convert string to uppercase and lowercase \nEnter 5 to compare two strings \n Enter 4 to find substring of given string \n Enter 3 to concatenate two strings \nEnter 6 to get characters at given index");
        choice = n.nextInt();
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Length of the given string is"+ s1.length());
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println(s1.toLowerCase());
                System.out.println(s1.toUpperCase());
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Enter another string:");
                String s2 = n.nextLine();
                System.out.println(s1.concat(s2));
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Enter begin index and end index:");
                int bInd = n.nextInt();
                int eInd = n.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Substring of given string is "+ s1.substring(bInd, eInd));
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Enter another string to compare:");
                String s3=n.nextLine();
                boolean result = s1.equals(s3);
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("Enter the index number:");
                int index = n.nextInt();
                System.out.println(s1.charAt(index));
                break;
            default: 
                System.out.println("Enter appropriate option:");
        }
    }
}
```

The error appears in case 3 and 5

Comment: It doesn't consider the second string input

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Scanner class reading strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466418/java-scanner-class-reading-strings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do a `n.nextInt()` it doesn't include the new line character.
So when you do `n.nextLine()` inside your switch, it just returns an empty string....

To Fix,
include `n.nextLine()` just after your `n.nextInt()` statement to flush out the new line character.

Comment: Yep as mentioned a million times before.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct. It will solve that issue.