# How to fix nextLine error so that both words are printed?

Tags: java

The code below works perfectly when ran, but if you enter two words in the "bands" question you'll only get one printed back.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    String name;
    name = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Hello " + name);
    System.out.println("What is your age?");
    int years;
    years = scan.nextInt();
    int ageInMonths;
    ageInMonths = years * 12;
    System.out.print("Your age is ");
    System.out.print(ageInMonths);
    System.out.println(" in months");
    System.out.println("What are your favorite two bands?");
    String bands = scan.next();
    System.out.println("I like >>" + bands + "<<too!");
  }
}
```

Comment: user scan.nextLine() instad of next();

Comment: if you use scan.nextLine instead of just next, it won't give you a chance to respond

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/2970947

Comment: as mentioned in the post from the link, you have to remove the linefeeds from the previous readings (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0):

The method `next()` from the class [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) will return only the next token.

As written  in the oracle docu:

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A
>   complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the
>   delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to
>   scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

The default delimiter ist a space, so if your band name will contain more then one word, it will not work.

For reading a whole line of input user `nextLine()`

If you want to have both band names separatly, call `nextLine()` twice to get each input separatly:

```
System.out.println("What are your favorite two bands?");
String band1 = scan.nextLine();
String band2 = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("I like >>" + band1 + " and " + band2 + "<<too!");
```

In this case the user has to press 'enter' after each input.

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in the comment of Elliott Frisch, other readXXX methods will not remove the lineendings from the inputstream.
see:
[stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/2970947](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/2970947)

You can use nextLine() for every input or remove the lineending after each reading. Sample with your code:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    String name;
    name = scan.next();
    scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Hello " + name);
    System.out.println("What is your age?");
    int years;
    years = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    int ageInMonths;
    ageInMonths = years * 12;
    System.out.print("Your age is ");
    System.out.print(ageInMonths);
    System.out.println(" in months");
    System.out.println("What are your favorite two bands?");
    String bands = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("I like >>" + bands + "<<too!");
```

API References:

[next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next())

[nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())

Answer (score 0):

To get a full string with multiple words (until `enter` press) you should use `scan.nextLine()` instead of `scan.next()` (`scan.next()` is use to read next word only).

Do not forget to add an extra `scan.nextLine()` after scan.nextInt()`and before`scan.nextLine()` (see it in [Java Scanner class reading strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466418/java-scanner-class-reading-strings)):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.print("What is your name? ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Hello " + name);

        System.out.print("What is your age? ");
        int years = scan.nextInt();
        int ageInMonths = years * 12;
        System.out.println("Your age is " + ageInMonths + " in months");

        System.out.print("What are your favorite two bands? ");
        scan.nextLine();    // extra one after scan.nextInt() - it retrieves a empty string
        String bands = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("I like >>" + bands + "<< too!");
    }
}
```

---

Demo, console output:

```
What is your name? John Doe
Hello John Doe
What is your age? 666
Your age is 7992 in months
What are your favorite two bands? one two three
I like >>one two three<< too!
```